# How can I filter out specific column from a CSV file in Perl?

Tags: perl, csv

I am just a beginner in Perl and need some help in filtering columns using a Perl script.
I have about 10 columns separated by comma in a file and I need to keep 5 columns in that file and get rid of every other columns from that file. How do we achieve this?

Thanks a lot for anybody's assistance.

cheers,
Neel

Comment: Please provide more detail, especially what differentiates the columns. An example of the data would be great.

Answer (score 20):

Have a look at [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV) (or [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV_XS)) to parse CSV files in Perl.  It's available on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) or you can probably get it through your package manager if you're using Linux or another Unix-like OS.  In Ubuntu the package is called libtext-csv-perl.

It can handle cases like fields that are quoted because they contain a comma, something that a simple split command can't handle.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what Text::CSV_XS is, or how it differs from Text::CSV, but when I installed libtext-csv-perl, I evidently got both.

Comment: _XS means external subroutine, meaning that it's written in another language (usually C) , and results in faster results. In case of Text::CSV and Text_CSV_XS, the author of this module  was kind enough to provide a Perl only implementation (Text::CSV) and a faster C implementation (Text::CSV_XS).

Answer (score 6):

CSV is an ill-defined, complex format (weird issues with quoting, commas, and spaces). Look for [a library](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Snail-CSV/lib/Snail/CSV.pm) that can handle the nuances for you and also give you conveniences like indexing by column names.

Of course, if you're just looking to split a text file by commas, look no further than @Pax's solution.

Answer (score 5):

Use split to pull the line apart then output the ones you want (say every second column), create the following xx.pl file:

```
while(<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    @fields = split (",",$_);
    print "$fields[1],$fields[3],$fields[5],$fields[7],$fields[9]\n"
}
```

then execute:

```
$ echo 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 | perl xx.pl
2,4,6,8,10
```

Comment: Do not just use split unless you are confident the values don't contain any commas

Comment: I think the definition of "CSV" precludes that

Comment: Some variants of CSV allow use of commas inside of quotes.

Comment: I like this solution best for a beginner. Bring in modules later.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about CSV files in windows (e.g., generated from Excel), you will need to be careful to take care of fields that contain comma themselves but are enclosed by quotation marks.

In this case, a simple *split* won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use [Text::ParseWords](http://search.cpan.org/search?module=Text::ParseWords), which is in the standard library. Add

```
use Text::ParseWords;
```

to the top of Pax's example above, and then substitute

```
  my @fields = parse_line(q{,}, 0, $_);
```

for the split.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some of Perl's built in runtime options to do this on the command line:

`$ echo "1,2,3,4,5" | perl -a -F, -n -e 'print join(q{,}, $F[0], $F[3]).qq{\n}'`
`1,4`

The above will -a(utosplit) using the -F(ield) of a comma. It will then join the fields you are interested in and print them back out (with a line separator). This assumes simple data without nested comma's. I was doing this with an unprintable field separator (\x1d) so this wasn't an issue for me.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Went looking didn't find a nice csv compliant filter program thats flexible to be useful for than just a one-of, so I wrote one. Enjoy.

Basic usage is:

bash$ csvfilter [-r <columnTitle>]* [-quote] <csv.file>

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

use Text::CSV;

my $always_quote=0;

my @remove;
if ( ! GetOptions('remove:s'=> \@remove,
          'quote-always'=>sub {$always_quote=1;}) ) {
   die "$0:invalid option (use --remove  [--quote-always])";
}

my @cols2remove;

sub filter(@)
{
   my @fields=@_;
   my @r;
   my $i=0;
   for my $c (@cols2remove) {
       my $p;
       #if ( $i  $i ) {
       push(@r, splice(@fields, $i));
   }
   return @r;
}

# create just one if these
my $csvOut=new Text::CSV({always_quote=>$always_quote});

sub printLine(@)
{
    my @fields=@_;
    my $combined=$csvOut->combine(filter(@fields));
    my $str=$csvOut->string();
    if ( length($str) ) {
     print "$str\n";
    }
}

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

my $od;
open($od, "| cat") || die "output:$!";
while () {
    $csv->parse($_);
    if ( $. == 1 ) {
    my $failures=0;
    my @cols=$csv->fields;
    for my $rm (@remove) {
        for (my $c=0; $c$b} @cols2remove);
    }
    printLine($csv->fields);
}

exit(0);
\
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what people here said about processing comma-separated files, I'd like to note that one can extract the even (or odd) array elements using an array slice and/or map:

```
@myarray[map { $_ * 2 } (0 .. 4)]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite way to do CSV is using the [AnyData module](http://search.cpan.org/~jzucker/AnyData-0.10/AnyData.pm).  It seems to make things pretty simple, and removing a named column can be done rather easily.  [Take a look on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~jzucker/AnyData-0.10/AnyData.pm).

Answer (score -3):

This answers a much larger question, but seems like a good relevant bit of information.

The unix [cut](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/) command can do what you want (and a whole lot more).  It has been [reimplemented in Perl](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/cut_perl.txt).

Comment: Not really; cut cannot manage the mysteries of CSV with commas inside strings and so on.

Comment: I would probably not call those CSV files, then.

Comment: Plenty of other things call them CSV files, and in the presence of a good solution, we don't need to resort to less than good solutions :)